# Construction of the Stone space of a sigma-algebra

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra

Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra, $S(B)$ the set of ultrafilters on $B$, and $\lambda(a)=\{U\in S(B):a\in U\}$ for every $a\in B$. Then the set $S(B)$ equipped with the topology for which $\{\lambda(a):a\in B\}$ is an open base is called the Stone space of $B$.

Suppose now that $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that I want to construct the Stone space of $B$. Shall I now define $S(B)$ as the set of $\sigma$-complete ultrafilters on $B$, or shall I still define $S(B)$ as the set of ultrafilters on $B$?

Comment: Nothing changes. A $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra that has an extra property. In this context treat it as an algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\sigma$-algebra is a special case of a Boolean-algebra, so the Stone space (and its definition) stay exactly the same.

The space $S(B)$ will have other properties that reflect the $\sigma$-completeness of the algebra we start with, of course. I think Halmos' text has parts of it that deal with that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.